# Merging Legacy Data on Best Key

Tags: sql-server, join, case, databricks, predicate

I am bringing in a field from a legacy system that does not have a Primary Key-Foreign Key relationship with the new table. The data is transactional, and each line has a customer and sales rep.

The legacy field has a many to many relationship with customer (but only on some), but it goes to one to many when you link customer and sales rep. However, the data is messy and the transaction may not match to a sales rep exactly.

It seems that the best way to tackle this problem is to join on customer and sales rep when possible, if there is not a match, then just join on customer.

I was able to do this in Excel by using the following:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Customer_SalesRep_Combo, DataTable, 3, FALSE),VLOOKUP(Customer,Datatable,3,FALSE))
```

This function in excel works, but the spreadsheet is so large that it tends to crash, so I am trying to duplicate this using SQL code.

Note that the legacy system just outputs CSV files, so I uploaded that CSV to the cloud, and now I am using Databricks to convert that into a Spark dataframe, so I can use SQL logic on it.

Initially, my idea was to do a left join using both conditions (which matches 50k of my 80k) rows, and do a left join using one condition. I would then bring in the legacy field twice (twice if matched, once if not). Then I would use a CASE statement to only bring in the "soft match" if there was not a hard match. However, due to the many to many relationship, I would experience join duplication on the left join. Since I am also bringing in Sales Data, I cannot have any duplication. However, I would be able to live with some inaccuracy if I could just use the first match and suppress any duplication.

I have seen examples of using case statements in joins, but I do not know how to use that in this case. If I cannot get this to work, I will resort to iterating over the dataframes to match the logic in Scala, but I would prefer a SQL solution. 
My code is below. The real version contains more fields, but this is the simplest I could get while retaining the basic logic.

```
SELECT 
    InnerQry.Customer,
    InnerQry.SalesRep,
    InnerQry.Sales,
    CASE 
        WHEN InnerQry.LegacyFieldHard IS NULL 
           THEN InnerQry.LegacyFieldSoft
        ELSE InnerQry.LegacyFieldHard
    END AS LegacyField
FROM
    (SELECT 
         A.Customer,
         A.SalesRep, 
         A.Sales,
         B.LegacyFieldHard,
         C.LegacyFieldSoft
     FROM 
         DBS AS A
     LEFT JOIN 
         LEGACY AS B ON A.Customer = B.Customer AND A.SalesRep = B.SalesRep
     LEFT JOIN 
         LEGACY AS C ON A.Customer = B.Customer) AS InnerQry
```

Comment: When you join to C, you get the ones you want AND the ones already matched. Maybe explicitly exclude those?

Comment: E.g. LEFT JOIN LEGACY AS C ON A.Customer=B.Customer AND A.SalesRep <> C.SalesRep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you get multiple rows when you map based on just on Customer (Legacy C). To avoid this you can create a row number field and restrict it to 1, provided you don't really care which among that customer's records gets mapped:

```
SELECT 
    A.Customer,
    A.SalesRep, 
    A.Sales,
    COALESCE(B.LegacyField,C.LegacyField) as LegacyField
FROM DBS AS A
LEFT JOIN LEGACY AS B ON A.Customer=B.Customer AND A.SalesRep=B.SalesRep
LEFT JOIN 
    (select *,
            row_number() Over (partition by Customer order by SalesRep) as rownum1 
    from LEGACY) AS C ON A.Customer=C.Customer and C.rownum1=1
```

Also, you could use the COALESCE function directly, instead of the case statement. This will automatically use the first non-null value . i.e) C value will be taken only when B is NULL. Hope this helps.

Comment: That join logic is genius! I never considered using only the first row. I also never knew about the COALESCE function. I will test it when I get back in the office. Thank you!

Comment: This solution works perfectly. And it has helped me on a couple other projects as well. Merging new systems on legacy systems suck... @CR7SMS